# Как копировать данные из (index) в панели разработчика Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Как копировать код из вкладки (index) в панели разработчика Google Chrome через JS?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нажми ПКМ на html тег и там будет несколько способов копирования - выбери нужный.

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato нужно через JS скопировать

Comment: @Alex, я конечно не очень вас понял, но вы можете на нужной вкладки зайти в консоль и написать document.querySelector('html').innerHTML  , тогда он выдаст вам весь код страницы